# Is there a difference in performance between using (or not) "else" after a "if [condition]: break" inside a while loop?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, break

**I have a while loop controlled by a if [condition]: break statement.**

For example, see the following:

```
#option 1
i=0
while(i>=0)
    if [condition]:
        break
    else:
        [do something]
        i=i+1

# option 2
i=0
while(i>=0)
    if [condition]:
        break
    [do something]
    i=i+1
```

**Is there any difference in performance when using (or not) the "else" afterwards? Is there any reason to prefer one over another?**

@khelwood @DeepSpace, at first I was concerned about readability, then I had the doubt. My actual problem is a bit more complex, so I made this example to focus more on the "else" leftover. Anyway, the tips on loop control and readability are welcome.

I followed @Barmar suggestion and tested the bytecode using dist module and two functions (see code below). For brevity, I'm using a simple condition (i>10) and ignored the [do something] part.

```
import dis
def option1():
    i = 0
    while (i>=0):
        if (i>10):
            break
        else:
            i=i+1
    return

def option2():
    i = 0
    while (i>=0):
        if (i>10):
            break
        i=i+1
    return


dis.dis(option1)
dis.dis(option2)
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant but I noticed differences in some numbers of the two last columns.

Also, there is an additional operation **"24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE"** for option1 (between lines 6 and 8).

```
*option1:*

  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  4           4 SETUP_LOOP              32 (to 38)
        >>    6 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             10 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=)
             12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       36

  5          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
             18 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       26

  6          22 BREAK_LOOP
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6

  8     >>   26 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             28 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             30 BINARY_ADD
             32 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             34 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   36 POP_BLOCK

  9     >>   38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE

*option2:*

 12           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 13           4 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 36)
        >>    6 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             10 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=)
             12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       34

 14          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
             18 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       24

 15          22 BREAK_LOOP

 16     >>   24 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             26 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             28 BINARY_ADD
             30 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   34 POP_BLOCK

 17     >>   36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: There is no significant difference, unless you find one more readable than the other.

Comment: Look at the generated byte code. I'd be surprised if there's any difference.

Comment: @khelwood Readability-wise I find the first one worse than the second (useless indentation level), but both are not the best. @minovsor The more idiomatic way than both options is (unless you actually use `i` somewhere else in the loop) is just `while condition:`. No performance difference, just much more readable code

Comment: A third alternative is to put `[condition]` directly in the `while`.